# How to filter out records from a join of two dataframe d1 and d2 where for all column in d1 =!= all corresponding column in d2

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Basically I wanted to check if there any updated records are there in new file comparison to yesterday file. For eg. I have two files, "backup file" and "Current file", of which I am creating two dataframes namely bkpdataframe( alias "bdf") and currentdataframe( alias "cdf"). Below is the code I am writing for updated records.

```
val joined= bdf.join(cdf,Seq("_c0"),"left")

val updatedRecords= joined.filter( (cdf("_c0").isNotNull && ( cdf("_c1") =!= bdf("_c1") || cdf("_c2") =!= bdf("c2"))
```

Is there any generic code for checking all the columns. Basically I don't want to hard code the columns name ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `dataframe` contains unique `rows` then you can use `except` function. `except` function returns the records which are not similar in both the `dataframes` like df1-df2

```
val updatedRecords=bdf.except(cdf).count
if(updatedRecords>0) println("Record updated") else println("Record Not updated")
```

And If you want to find update records

```
val updatedRecDF=cdf.except(bdf)
```

Comment: I have tried using except () to find difference but is giving me more number of records. Also I guess except works on the whole row set and returns row if any of the columns has different value. Please correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: df1.except(df2)=> returns rows in df1 but not in df2

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a constraint while comparing 2 datasets that they must be of same signature i.e. same columnset and same ordering of columns.

Then you should have the joining columns as a list(jc_list)

Then, you can go like below to get your desired output:

jc_list1_df=bdf.select(jc_list)
jc_list2_df=cdf.select(jc_list)

Then you can compare them and create your desired output.

delete_jc_df=jc_list1_df.except(jc_list2_df)  --- deleted records
new_jc_df=jc_list2_df.except(jc_list1_df)  --- new records

Then you can join these joining columns with actual datasets to get all the other columns.

delete_df=delete_jc_df.join(bdf,jc_list,"inner")
insert_df=insert_jc_df.join(cdf,jc_list,"inner")

Now, if you want to find updated records, you can intersect the jc_list1 and jc_list2

jc_list_common=jc_list1.intersect(jc_list2)

now you get all other columns from cdf using these set,

common_df=cdf.join(jc_list_common,jc_list,"inner")

now you can do a minus operation between common_df and bdf to get only the updated set,

update_df=common_df.minus(bdf)   ---voila